# How to detect if a compiler supports static_assert?

Tags: c, macros, feature-detection, c11, static-assert

I want to detect, in source file, if the compiler used supports `static_assert`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In c11,  `static_assert` is an `assert.h` macro that expands to `_Static_assert`.

You can just use:

```
#include <assert.h>

#if defined(static_assert)
// static_assert macro is defined
#endif
```

Note that some compilers (e.g., IAR) also have a `static_assert` keyword extension even if they don't support C11.

As mentioned in the comments you can also check for c11:

```
#if (__STDC_VERSION >= 201112L)
// it is c11, static_assert is defined when assert.h is included
#endif
```

Comment: Then how does assert.h know if _Static_assert is supported?

Comment: @yshui, the standard header files like `assert.h` are provided by the platform, so they have their internal magic to know what is supported or not. That is exactly whey they are here, so you don't have to worry about such features.